# Помогите решить проблему с модулем pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Всё прекрасно работает, но программа говорит только на английском языке. Когда ввожу в engine.say() русские буквы, то ничего не работает.

Comment: может нужно сменить язык? я не думаю, что модуль умеет различать, буквы какого алфавита ему даются, я посмотрел парочку примеров в `г` `у` `г` `л`, и там везде выбирается локализация..

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо установит голоса, поддерживающие русский язык. По ссылке есть 3 вида голоса + некоторые программы на Python 3.8.x для пробы. voicelist.py отображает все доступные голоса, установленные в системе. Изменение голоса на другой найдёте в двух других файлах. Ссылка: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JKb07P5pfhRhYiT_XAt-GrZqeffGNpG1

Answer (score 0):

````
    import pyttsx3
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    tts.setProperty('voice', 'russian')
    engine.say("I will speak this text")
    engine.runAndWait()```
````

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]